# Run Excel.run in Browser - Nested Javascript Functions Objects Not running deepest code

Tags: javascript, excel, async-await, office-js

I'm trying to setup my Office Add-In to be able to run (mostly) outside of Excel in the browser. To do this, I'm testing if `Office` and `Excel` variables are set and if not, I'm basically just making dummy variables so the code will run (I expect if it needs these functions, the code to fail, but for now, just want to test in Edge outside of Office).

This question isn't really about Excel, just some background. I think my somewhat limited understanding of async and functions objects is coming into play.

I've stripped everything down to a MVCE and here is my code.

What I want to see and is not happening is getting the `console.log("commandsfunc");` to run, currently it doesn't error, but never gets to that code.

Here is a basic `index.html`:

```
<html>
        <head>
           <title>My External JavaScript Code!!!</title>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
           </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
</html>
```

and `test.js`:

```
var Excel = {}
Excel.run = async function (context) {
    console.log('Excel.Run')
    var context = {}
    return context
}

CommandsFunc(event)
async function CommandsFunc(event) {
    console.log('Excel')
    console.log(Excel)
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        //Start Func.
        console.log("commandsfunc");
        //End Func
    });
    console.log('Out')
}
```

Comment: your `Excel.run` never calls the function it's passed. (It bizarrely calls that function `context`, and then overwrites it with an empty object which it then returns?)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full working code @RobinZigmond , I didn't mean to overwrite context. Its a bit weird, but I didn't want to littler my code w/ booleans of `Is_Running_In_Office` so this allows me to just check if running in office and then pass some funcs to get it to move forward without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
var Excel = {}
Excel.run = async function(Excel_Run) {
  console.log('Excel.Run')
  //console.log(Excel_Run)
  var context = {}
  context.sync = function() { return true }
  Excel_Run(context) //This was the magic line! Run the code passed!
  return true
}

CommandsFunc(event)
async function CommandsFunc(event) {
    console.log('Excel')
    console.log(Excel)
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        //Start Func.
        console.log("commandsfunc");
        //End Func
    });
    console.log('Out')
}
```